# TableViewCell data called two times from TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get data from TableView to Cell. So I wrote `cell.count = groups[indexPath.row].count` in dataSource.
In TableViewCell `var count: Int!` is declared. When I print count in layoutSubviews() it calls same data two times so I can't do what I want. When I print groups[indexPath.row].count in dataSource method it print normally one time. How can I solve this problem?

Example)
if count sequence is 1 2 1 then in Cell count variable print 1 1 2 2 1 1

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show your code; both `cellForRow` and the relevant code from your cell?  The fact that the cell was laid out multiple times isn't a bug. Cells can be redrawn multiple times as the table view is laid out and scrolls etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I wrote the code because there was no code in your writing.

```
let groups : [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.groups.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowData = self.groups[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GROUP_CELL")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = rowData
        return cell!
    }
```

This will not output the contents of 'groups' twice. Is this what you want?